# Can you run a netty server (or use the netty client) in a glassfish container?  

Tags: glassfish, netty, akka

Looks like this [this netty doc article](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/http/package-summary.html) has a suggestion of how to do this... 
But can someone point me to some code that implements it? My ultimate goal by the way is to support being able to use Akka 2.x remoting from within a glassfish 3.1.x based app.

The same question goes for using the netty client from glassfish 3.1.x. Hopefully there are examples people can point out.

Answer (score 0):

The [Akka](http://akka.io/) (2.0.3 is what I used) framework does exactly this!
So there is an existence proof that it can be done.

In the case of Akka, they've done a beautiful job making it easy to use netty's functionality with a great protobuf serialization scheme over it and actors (available for both Java and Scala) on top of that.